# win32api.getasynckeystate cannot detect keys when focused on other application

Tags: python

It has been like 3 questions in a row, and I tried different ways to ask but failed to get an exact answer. The question is clear with the title. The keyboard pressed key is not detected when window is focused on other application, any help?  The code is almost same as that of Sentdex who uses it to play GTA 5 .

```
import win32api as wapi
import time

left = 37
up = 38
right = 39
down = 40

keyList = ["Q","W","E","A","S","D",left,up,right,down]


def key_check():
    keys = []
    for key in keyList:
        if str(key).isdigit():
            if wapi.GetAsyncKeyState(key):
                if key==37:
                    key="left"
                elif key==38:
                    key="up"
                elif key==39:
                    key="right"
                elif key==40:
                    key="down"
                keys.append(key)
        else:
            if wapi.GetAsyncKeyState(ord(key)):
                keys.append(key)
    print(keys)
    return keys
```